# How to make default group write permission in specific folder

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have directory called `/home/bob/public_html`

I have set gid bit on on that directory that all new files have group bob.

but i also want that all files should have default group write permission on all files which will be created in public_html directory

Comment: Maybe with umask but that's user specific not directory specific...

Comment: This isn't really programming related, so it should be moved to unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with the standard set of permissions in linux. However, you can use ACLs to do it. It is a bit more complex, but also offers a lot more flexibility. [Here](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/suse9.0/adminguide-9.0/node27.html) is a guide to ACLs, including default permissions. In order to be able to use them, you have to install the userspace utilities like setfacl and getfacl and mount the partition with the ACL option.